# Reference Component - WCM Mode value not coming as expected - Adobe AEM/CQ

Tags: aem

Following is the scenario

1. `Page A` has a component in which we are reading `wcmmode.edit` to determine if its edit mode and we are on author instance and displaying a certain section based on sightly condition `data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}"`. If this page is opened stand alone, page shows the content.
2. `Page B` uses [Reference Component](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/page-authoring/default-components/editmode.html#Reference) to reuse the content authored in `Page A`, `path` reference to `Page A` is stored in JCR structure of `Page B`

When I am opening `Page B` the content of `Page A` reference is not visible. It seems as if `wcmmode.edit` value is not coming as expected when using through reference.

Checked the [Reference Component](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/page-authoring/default-components/editmode.html#Reference) implementation. It internally uses `sling:include` to point to reference path.

When user is on author edit mode, the reference component should behave as per current mode. Is there any separate configuration for this, didn't find anything in documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the code for reference.jsp, very first line is - 
    `WCMMode mode = WCMMode.DISABLED.toRequest(request);`
This sets the WCMmode as DISABLED for the request and when you include the referenced component, that what it receives thus bypassing any edit logic.

You could effectively extend the reference component and have your own logic there which preserves the wcm mode.

Comment: I wonder, is there a specific intent Adobe has to design reference component like this? If we override/extend, would there be any side effect?

Comment: All components are meant for extension to be customized to individual project needs. They way I have designed referenced component in my projects is in a way not to allow it to be edited outside its own space/page.

With a multiple author environments its quite possible that the author misses the fact that its a reference while updating it where as need could be that it wasn't to be updated at the origin.